# Is there an algorithm for comparing if statements?

Tags: algorithm

Is there an algorithm and/or tool for detecting if two sets of `if` statements with the same conditions are equivalent? When I say "equivalent" - I mean that they execute the same code for all given inputs. For example:

```
# set 1
if a
  if b
    someMethod()
  end
end

# set 2
if a && b
  someMethod()
end

# set 3
if a || b
  someMethod()
end
```

Given these 3 sets of `if` statements, you could consider set 1 and set 2 to be "equivalent" in that `someMethod` only gets executed when a and b are true. Likewise set 1 and set 3 are not equivalent since `someMethod` won't get executed by set 1 when a is true and b is false, but will be executed in set 3 under those same conditions.

Comment: There aren't general methods, because the `if` conditions could be arbitrarily complex -- e.g. they might depend on what the millionth digit of pi is.

Comment: This sounds like an application of satisfiability which is well known to be NP complete.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - I've revised my question to specify that all of the if-statement-sets have to have the same inputs as conditions.

Comment: @Quirliom - interesting... I hadn't heard of that before, so after some quick googling, how would proving that various sets are satisfiable help determine that the sets are "equivalent"?

Comment: @mralexlau: In that case (and assuming further that they are only combined via logical operators like `&&` and `||`) it's easy: just calculate a truth table for each, and see if they're identical.  This table will have 2^n rows if there are n inputs.

Comment: @mralexlau: Nested `if`s function like `&&`, so they will work too.

Comment: I think you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus. If the two if statements are equal, then you can derive a proof of it.

Comment: Your question seemes to suggest of code-clone detection, which is not just specific to if-statements, but rather any type of duplicate code doing the same thing. There has been some research in detecting duplicate codes using `Abstract Syntax Trees`. E.g. : http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/icsm98.pdf

Comment: there are more ways to do this ... 1.see my answer. 2.convert statements to the same normalized form by use of demorgan's rules/laws and compare them. 3.create truth table and compare it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [Karnaugh Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) which is standard for non sequential logic synthesis and analysis.

1. **create Karnaugh Map for each set of `if`s**
2. **compare the maps**

   if the map is the same then the if statements are equivalent if not then they are different.

Sorry for a short answer but I do not have a clue what else to add because this is basic knowledge.

**[edit1] just your case ...**

[image: example]

- `set1 == set2`
- `set3` is different

Comment: While you answer is appreciated, what may be "basic knowledge" to you may not be basic to others :P

Comment: @mralexlau sorry I am used to that this basic logic stuff and reasoning was teached globally back in my school days ... now there is more and more crap in the schools (at least here in my and near countries) and not the useful things like I am used to