# Designing a System Timer(Porgrammable Logic Timer)

Tags: digital-logic, flip-flop, circuit-diagram

**System timer**

Computers contain a timer containing programmable channels. Programmable
channels mean timers of different durations. How to design such a circuit with four
programmable channels, each disabled initially. An enable input, two channel select
inputs and 4 lines for duration input can set any channel to a given duration from 1-
15. Zero means to disable a channel. Four output lines correspond to the channels and
are set high as soon as the corresponding timer expires.

**Inputs**
Clock Pulse CP

Input Available IA

Channel Select CS0, CS1

Duration D0…D3

**Outputs**

Timer Expire : TA, TB, TC, TD

I want to use Discrete logic ICs like Flip-Flops,Logic Gates,Decoders,Multiplexers,Encoders, etc.Data input is to be done using buttons(Push-buttons) and output should be displayed on LEDs. The clock should be common.

Comment: what do you want to use specific IC like PIT / MCU / FPGA / or Discrete Logic IC ? the answer is werry different for each. Also how do you want to input and output data (buttons,keyboard,LED,Display,Screen ...) add as much specific as you can ... brw there are electrical engineering and MCU sites even here on SO better suited for this kind of questions. Also do you want separate clock per each channel or common clock ?

Comment: I want to use Discrete logic ICs like Flip-flops,Logic Gates,Decoders,Multiplexers etc.Data input is to be done using buttons(Push-buttons) and output should be displayed on LEDs. The clock should be common.

Comment: which technology TTL, DTL,CMOS ? What should happen after time expires ... next period I mean ... or you want just single shot timing ?

Comment: I want to use CMOS and it should be a single-shot sort of thing.Even a circuit diagram will help me a lot.I want a simplest most design.

Comment: I strongly feel you would have more luck on http://electronics.stackexchange.com . I will try to draw some simplified circuit but it will take a while ... have no tool for it installed so paint would have to do ...

Comment: I'll be very thankful to you for this favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Single shot Timer consists of:**

1. **n-bit binary counter**

   driven by the input clock source `CP` and reseted by start input. With each clock pulse increments its value. The reset input should be hooked up to the timer start signal.
2. **n-bit LATCH register**

   to store the timer Interval value (your per channel duration `D0..D3`)
3. **n-bit comparator**

   to compare counted value and the Interval value. The **XOR** of equal bits is zero so if you or all xored bits together the result is `0` if both **LATCH** register value and Counter value are the same.
4. **output flip flop**

   to remember expiration of timer (for non pulse mode operation) the output is your `TA.TB,TC,TD` The start impulse should also reset the **RS** on circuit I do this by **WR** but I suspect you will have Start signal separately instead...

Something like this:

[image: timer example]

You need to take into account the negations and auxiliary inputs of used ICs to make it work properly (some has negated WR some not ... the same goes for all pins so always check datasheet). So do not forget to add the chip selects and output enables signals to their working conditions.

**multi channel timer**

Well you just add the **LATCH** and comparators for each channel each connected to the same counter. The tricky part is the channel selection and starting part. you need to add decoder `1 from 4` to select the correct **LATCH** while setting the `D0..D3`. To draw a circuit for that part I would need to know more about the purpose of this ... Also if you set the Intervals only manually then you can use DIP switches instead the **LATCH** and the selection circuitry making it all much simpler.

All of above can be made just from **NAND** or **NAND** gates instead of concrete **IC** implementation. For that you need to use [Karnaugh Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26334878/2521214) and Boolean algebra.

It is a while I done something with raw gates as now is much easier cheaper faster to use **MCU/FPGA** for all of this so beware I could have miss something trivial (like negation gate somewhere)... anyway even then this should got the idea behind timers

**BTW C++ representation of this is:**

```
int cnt=0,D=?;
bool TA=0;
for (;;)
 {
 if (cnt==D) TA=1;
 cnt=(cnt+1)&15;
 }
```

**[Edit1] the 4 channels version**

[image: 4 channel timer]

This is based on the above text. There is also another option with less components that use 4 nibble RAM module instead of LATCH registers and decoder composing of single timer continuously looping through all channels by 4 x times CP multiplied clock (for example by XORing delayed CP signals).

[image: timer loop]

Comment: @NaumanShakir I strongly recommend to test the circuit in logic simulator or directly on breading board before going into PCB. PS had wrong negator in image now it should be correct

Comment: can you give me a simple circuit diagram for all of the four given channels?

Comment: @NaumanShakir added the full circuit for booth direct and looped version of 4 channel single shot timer.