# Simplifying the boolean expression (A && B) || (A && !B && C)

Tags: math, boolean-logic, simplify

I'm so confused currently while trying to simplify a boolean expression. I know the solution but not the correct way to achieve it.

What law makes `(A && B) || (A && !B && C)` the same as `(A && B) || (A && C)`

Why can i leave the `!B`?

Comment: Most likely [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#:~:text=In%20propositional%20logic%20and%20Boolean,a%2019th-century%20British%20mathematician.) however much easier and safer for simplification is to use [Karnaugh Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24054153/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

Since (in simplified notation):

B+B'C = B+B+B'C = B(C+C')+B(C'+C)+B'C = BC+BC'+BC'+BC+B'C = BC+BC'+BC'+(B+B')C = BC+BC'+1C = B(C+C')+C = B+C

we have

AB + AB'C = A (B + B'C) = A(B+C) = AB + AC

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any *law*, but I will try to explain it.

For us to reach the check of `!B` we must acknowledge two things:

1. `A` *must be* TRUE
2. `B` *must be* FALSE

If `A` is false we can short-circuit out of both checks `(A && B)` and `(A && !B && C)` because `A` is evaluated first and we are only comparing with `&&`.

If `A` is true and `B` is true, the second condition is not evaluated.

Therefore, to reach `!B`, `A` must be true and `B` must be false as stated above. If that's the case then `!B` will *always* evaluate to TRUE in the second condition, and can be removed.