# How to simplify if statements

Tags: c, algorithm, if-statement

How can I simplify below if statements?, I'm trying to achieve the possibly most efficient code.

```cpp
// doSomething based on x value and y value   
void doSomething(x int, y int) {

    //x not zero and y not zero
    if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
      //do a

      //do b if x greater or equal y
      //else do c
      if (x >= y) {
          //do b
      } else (x < y) {
          //do c
      }

      return;
        
    }

    //do b if x not zero and y zero
    if (x != 0 && y == 0) {
        //do b
        return;
    }

    //do e if both x and y zero
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        //do e
        return;
    }
}
```

What is the most concise and efficient way to simplify?

Comment: The use of `else if` and `else` statements would certainly help. Done correctly, you can eliminate all of the `return` statements.

Comment: Before you start simplifying the code, you need to fix the code. For example, you've got `if x!=0 && y!=0` and inside that `if` you've got `if (x==0 && y!=0)`. The second `if` can't ever be true because you've already verified that `x!=0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an algorithm for comparing if statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051418/is-there-an-algorithm-for-comparing-if-statements)

Comment: see the linked answer You can use Karnaugh Maps not just for comparing but also for simplification of boolean expresions ...

Comment: What language is this in? Although most languages have relatively similar constructs, they differ in the details of conditionals, pattern-matching, switch cases, dictionaries, etc., and the "best" way to rewrite such an if-forest might be different from language to language.

Comment: @Spektre, nice reference, I should have done it before actually code.

Comment: @Stef, it's actually written in swift, but I edited the code to c style.

Comment: @DdlElo Since you've edited your question and modified your code since I posted my answer, and I'm too lazy to check everything again, I can no longer guarantee that your code is equivalent to the code in my answer.

Comment: @DdlElo its basic knwoledge in EE digital circuit synthesis but less known in programming community ...

Comment: I would simplify it by removing all unnecessary comments :)

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your code is equivalent to:

```
if (x == 0)
{
  if (y == 0)
    do e
}
else if (y != 0)
{
  if (x < y)
    do a,c
  else
    do a,b
}
```

In particular:

- if `x=0 && y!=0` or `y=0 && x!=0`, then do nothing;
- the two branches `//do b if x not zero and y zero` and `//do d if x zero and y not zero` are unreachable in your code.

Answer (score 1):

#### History:

The code in the question was changed several times. This answer is based on the [original version of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69357061/1). That code is shown below, minimally modified so that it's compilable C code:

```
void original(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == y && x != 0 && y != 0) {
        // do a
        // do b
        return;
    }

    if (x < y && x != 0 && y != 0) {
        // do a
        // do c
        return;
    }

    if (x > y && x != 0 && y != 0) {
        // do a
        // do b
        return;
    }

    if (x != 0 && y == 0) {
        // do a
        // do b
        return;
    }

    if (x == 0 && y != 0) {
        // do a
        // do d
        return;
    }

    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        // do e
        return;
    }
}
```

#### Motivation:

The advantage of the original code is that it clearly covers all possible input combinations.

The first three `if` statements handle the cases where `x` and `y` are non-zero (with `x==y`, `x<y`, and `x>y` handled separately). Then the remaining three `if` statements handle the cases where one or both are zero. That covers everything.

The disadvantages of the original code are:

1. Many of the comparisons are repeated several times, e.g. `y != 0` is checked four times. Given that branching statements tend to be time consuming in contemporary (year 2021) processors, redundant comparisons are something to be avoided <sup>1</sup>.
2. The code violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Specifically, `do a` appears in five locations, and `do b` appears in three locations. So any refactoring of the code should attempt to eliminate the repetition.

<sup>1) The optimizer may be able reduce the number of comparisons. However, that's hard to test without real code.</sup>

#### Refactoring with nested `if` statements:

If we focus on the DRY principle first, we notice that `a` appears in 5 of 6 code blocks. Only the case for `e` doesn't invoke `a`. So the logical choice is to handle `e` first. This results in the following code structure:

```
if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
    // do e
} else {
    // do a
    // everything else (note that either x is not zero, or y is not zero)
}
```

Within the "everything else", we have `do b` three times, `do c` once, and `do d` once. So the next step is to handle `c` and `d`, leaving only `b`. The refactored code looks like this:

```
void nestedIf(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        // do e
    } else {
        // do a

        if (x == 0) {   
            // do d
        } else {
            if (y != 0 && x < y) {
                // do c
            } else {
                // do b
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Refactoring with early `return` statements:

Some coding standards insist that a function shall only return from one location. The nested `if` code meets that requirement, but at the cost of being a little messy due to nesting. Using early returns eliminates the nesting, and may allow the code for `a` thru `e` to be implemented inline without additional functions (assuming they're only a few lines each). The refactored code looks like this:

```
void earlyReturn(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        // do e
        return;
    }

    // do a

    if (x == 0) {   // x is zero and y is not zero
        // do d
        return;
    }

    if (y != 0 && x < y) {  // x and y are both not zero, and x < y
        // do c
        return;
    }

    // do b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming `a()`, `b()`, and `e()` have the same type (`fxtype`)

```
fxtype *fx[4] = { e, NULL, b, a }; // NULL when x==0, y!=0
fx[2*!!x + !!y](x, y);
```

Change `a` to include `c()` and `b()`

```
int a(int x, int y) {
    // do previous a()
    if (x < y) c(x, y); else b(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```